# Plotting double inequality only for integer values

Tags: equation-solving, plotting

`RegionPlot` is plotting for all values. And using `ListPlot` I can only evaluate one inequality. How can I plot this type of inequality:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha+1} \leq \frac{\sum_{i=0}^k i^a}{\sum_{i=0}^k i^b} \leq 1+\alpha$$.
$a$,$b$ are const (I know values $a$ and $b$).

I want to plot dependency between $\alpha$ and $k$ only for integer values of $k$ and $\alpha$ is only from $(0,1]$.

So I tried to use `ListPlot` (as you suggested me in previous post).

```
ListPlot[Table[{k, (-1) + (Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/
       Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}])}, {k, 1, n}], PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 Filling -> Top]
```

But I don't know how to add here the second inequality.

I tried also to use `RegionPlot`. This commend is easier for me, because I know how to add the second inequality, but I don't know how to restrict that `k` should be only integer

```
RegionPlot[(Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/
      Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}]) <= 
   1 + f && (Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/
      Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}]) >= 1/f, {k, 1, n}, {f, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: It is duplicate of your previous question because `ListPlot` with appropriate [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html) it is what you want. It will be better if you update your previous question instead of new one.

Comment: I think it's not, because here qe have to inequalities, not one

Comment: Always try to post all the relevant code you can build for your question

Comment: @belisarius I made edit and I posted what I tried to do

Comment: Well done! Always try to post code

Comment: you hace THREE params in there: alpha, a and b

Comment: @belisarius No, I know a and b (I wrote that this value are const)

Comment: @Silvia I made an mistake, now everything is ok

Comment: OK I see that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `RegionPlot` and to add in a constraint that the `k` value be near an integer. For example:

```
a = 1.5; b = 1.7; k = 20; n = 10; 
RegionPlot[(Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}]) <= 1 + f 
        && (Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}]) >=  1/(1 + f) 
        && ((k - Floor[k] < 0.1) || (Ceiling[k] - k < 0.1)), 
            {k, 1, n}, {f, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

We can even solve the problem exactly. First, set up all the equations

```
a = 1.5; b = 1.6;
eqns=Table[ 1/(1 + f)<=Sum[i^a, {i, 0, k}]/Sum[i^b, {i, 0, k}] <= (1 + f), {k, 1, 10}]
```

and then use `Reduce` to solve:

```
Reduce[#] & /@ eqns
{f >= 0, f >= 0.053026, f >= 0.0893559, f >= 0.117241, f >= 0.139986, 
 f >= 0.159254, f >= 0.176007, f >= 0.190851, f >= 0.204194, f >= 0.216325}
```

which shows the exact values of `f` that work for each possible value of `k`.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is helpful. But unfortunately I need an integer, not something what is near, because otherwise I will not be able to read

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica seems to handle the discrete values of k for sum:

```
f[a_, k_, x_, y_] := 
 1/(1 + a) <= Sum[j^x, {j, 0, k}]/Sum[j^y, {j, 0, k}] <= 1 + a
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[f[x, y, a, b], {y, 1, 20}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["k", 20], Style[\[Alpha], 20]}], {a, 1, 2, 
  ControlType -> LabeledSlider}, {b, 1, 2, 
  ControlType -> LabeledSlider}]
```

[image]